# Convert relative image to base64 or use your relative image to upload to firebase storage using node

Tags: firebase, base64, nodes, firebase-storage

Has anyone achieved this before? I keep getting the following error below. 
I am also using [base64-img](https://github.com/douzi8/base64-img) to convert my local images to base64.
Error:

```
throw invalidFormat(format, 'Invalid character found');
        ^
FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: String does not match format 'base64': Invalid character found
```

Request:

```
    ...

    import base64Img from 'base64-img';
    const app = express()

    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
      res.send('hello world')

      let url = './images/girl.jpg'

      base64Img.base64(url, function(err, data) {
        console.log(data)
        let fileName = "girl.jpg";

        const metadata = {
          contentType: "image/jpeg"
        };

        let strImage = data.split("base64,")[1];
        console.log(strImage)
        let storageRef = storage.ref(`images/${fileName}`);
        storageRef.putString(strImage, 'base64', metadata)
      });

    ....
```

Comment: Have you tried it without the data.split?

Comment: @AndréKool - same error. Even, If I was able to upload a local image that would suffice. I am creating profiles on the file, and my images are local. Otherwise I would set the imageURL in my database.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to scratch converting my image to base64 and upload the local image. This was the original task I was going for. After much digging this works for uploading your relative image to firebase storage.

```
let filename = './images/girl.jpg' <--my local path in my project
  const bucket = admin.storage().bucket();
  bucket.upload(filename, {
    //destination: 'users/images/girl.jpg', <---Optional if you want folders, leave blank for root
    gzip: true,
    metadata: {
      cacheControl: 'public, max-age=31536000'
    }
  }).then(() => {
    console.log(`${filename} uploaded.`);
  }).catch(err => {
    console.error('ERROR:', err);
  });
```